# Dynamics Webhook Registration Issue

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions, dynamics-365

I am facing issue in registering a webhook in Microsoft's Dynamics 365 based on the steps provided in the documentation for SalesOrder Entity. Here is the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/api-reference/v2.0/dynamics-subscriptions#register-a-webhook-subscription

I have created a Http Trigger on Azure Portal and wanted to register to Dynamics 365 webhook for a particular entity. Whenever, an update happens for that entity in Dynamics 365, the Http trigger will be called and the notifications will be seen on the portal. Currently, the notification url I provided in setting up the webhook is giving me an error. Here is the screenshot:

[image: error for registering webhook]